# EC2 instance not getting pinged

Tags: amazon-ec2, ping, putty, winscp

I have ec2 instance running and which is linked with elastic ip.
when I ping it from local machine then It shows request time out because of which I am not able connect to it via putty and win scp.

I am facing this issue from last 2days.
It was working well for last 2 months.
Please help.
My instance is runig and healthy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ping an EC2 instance from your local machine you need to allow inbound Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) traffic.  Please check your Security Groups to make sure this is allowed.  Remember that all inbound traffic is disable by default.  You may need to establish a rule similar to this one (JSON format):

```
"AllowIngressICMP": {
"Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
"Properties": {
"GroupId": <Your Security Group here>,
"IpProtocol": "icmp",
"FromPort": "-I",
"ToPort": "-I",
"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
```

** The -I means "every port"

Comment: its already done. and I am facing this issue from last 2days only., previously it was working fine

Comment: Be sure to check that inbound traffic is allowed on port 22 (ssh).  Maybe your instance was stopped and restarted.  If the instance is not in a VPC, then your Elastic IP address was disassociated from it.   If this is the case, please check additional information at:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html